# PDF not loading in WKWebview in Mac-Catalyst (Sonoma 14.0)

Tags: ios, macos, pdf, wkwebview, mac-catalyst

In my application, we load pdf in WKWebView. In macOS 13 it's working fine, but when I update to macOS 14.0 then after it displays a white screen. Here is my code:

```
var pdfData: Data? = nil
do{
     pdfData = try Data(contentsOf: anUrl)
     if let aData = pdfData {
          webView?.load(aData, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL.init(string: path as String)!)
     }
}catch{
     print("error in pdfData")
     CommanMethods.sharedInstance.showAlert(title: "", message: "PreviewAlertKey".localized(withComment: ""), viewController: self)
}
```

Comment: Why not load `anUrl` directly into the web view instead of first loading it into `Data`? Is this a local URL or a remote URL? If remote, you definitely do not want to use `Data(contentsIf:)`. If local, consider `QLPreviewController` instead of `WKWebView`.

Comment: got any solution to the issue?

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar no

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar got any solution?

Comment: @Jones not got any solution